# Laggy parrallax on Macbook with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, parallax, smooth-scrolling

I have been struggling with this for a long time now, I can't really figure out how the smoothen my parrallaxes on my website using Chrome on macbooks.

The website is Asebratentunet.no
Under the site index-1.html the parrallaxes are laggy, under index-2.html the parrallax works smooth. After som research I saw that it was the Google embeded map that made my parrallax smooth under page index-2.html. Isnt that strange?

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Or does anyone understand how the Google Map is making Index-2.html smooth?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: This is not an issue with your code; `index-1.html` is perfectly smooth - if not smoother than `index-2.html` - on my machine:
`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36`
You should test your page on a few other machines and see this for yourself - as this is likely to be an issue with your Mac -

Comment: Thank you for your response. But if what you are saying is correct, why is the problem dissapearing when I embed a google map?

Comment: I'm not sure - taking a closer look, I do not see any reason for that... 

Can you verify that it will start lagging if you remove the Google Map?

Comment: Yes. I tried to compare the files index-1 and index-2 by ripping apart what was different. At last, I tried to embed the google map from index-2 to index-1 and the lagginess quit.

Comment: Interesting-! I have a theory or two, but I will have to closely examine this more closely, later - can you tell menyour mac's specs? Number of cores/threads and RAM is all I need to know.

Comment: MacBookPro11,1
  Prosessornavn: Intel Core i5
  Prosessorhastighet: 2,6 GHz
  Antall prosessorer: 1
  Totalt antall kjerner: 2
  Nivå 2-buffer (per kjerne): 256 kB
  Nivå 3-buffer: 3 MB
Ram: 16 gb

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
Everything was fixed after adding a custom scroller.